# php grouped table sorting 1 off

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, grouping

I am trying to achieve a sorted list with a section separator from a mysql table via php, but am having a bit of trouble. Instead of putting my soup in the soup header like I want, I am putting it in the following header(like I don't want)!

Here is the visual output:

```
2-Soup
3-Salad
    2   Soup     Demo: Tom KaKai
4-Entree
    3   Salad    Demo: Spinach Salad
    4   Entree   Demo: Pork Chop
    4   Entree   Demo: Spicy Topped Shrimp
```

here is my code:

```
 $cat = null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if( $row['catnum'] != $cat )
    {
        echo '<h1>' . $row['catnum'] . '-' . $row['ctgry'] . '</h1>';
        $cat = $row['catnum'];
    }
   echo "<table><tr><td>" . $row['catnum'] . " </td><td>" . $row['ctgry'] . "</td><td> " . $row['Shrt_Desc'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source? You have an open table tag in the loop but no close tag. Also what is your query?

Comment: Not sure if it's the answer to your problem, but you are creating a new table on *every* loop iteration and not closing your `table` tag, so each loop iteration, you are creating another table within the last table. That might have something to do with it. I assume you only want to create a new table with each new header and add rows to that table for each entry in that same category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing your `<table>` tag and are starting a new table for every DB row retrieved, so structurally your HTML page is a total mess.

You'd want something like this:

```
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['catnum'] != $cat) {
       if (!$first) {
           echo '</table>'; // close the table if we're NOT the first row being output.
       }

       $first = false; // no longer the first table, so disable this check.
       echo '<h1> etc...';
       echo '<table>'; // start new table
       $cat = $row['catnum'];
    }
    echo '<tr><td>' etc.... // output a table row
}
```

This code will only output the `<table>` and `<h1`> stuff when you change categories.